# Is it possible to debug UI App and AAR simultaneously?

Tags: android, debugging, aar

we are working on an android project and want to develop two binaries that work together: a UI App, and an AAR library back end.  The idea is that the AAR may be used in the future with other UIs.

So, we have one developer working on the AAR project, and another developer working on a UI project.  Is there any way to debug the two simultaneously; i.e., run the UI+AAR and trace execution back and forth between the two, setting breakpoints and watches on either side, etc.?

I've done the analogous thing in .NET, develop a UI EXE+DLL back end with multiple "projects" in a single "solution", debugging the whole thing at once; it's a really nice way to develop.  Is there any way to achieve this with android studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add both parts to one project as **modules**. Then you add a direct dependency in your UI module to the second module. Now you can debug both at the same time.

This is the best solution if you also want to be able to make changes in both parts.

---

If you want to debug any library in combination with your code, Android Studio also supports breakpoints in decompiled files (or in the attached source if there is one).

Comment: Android Studio also supports breakpoints in decompiled files (or in the attached source if there is one) >> How this can be done?I have an AAR (with sources) and want to debug it.DO I have to include both(AAR and Sources) or Only Sources or only AAR to be able to put the break points and navigate inside the AAR code?

Comment: The aar is necessary to set breakpoints. Sources are not required, but decompiled code might not be easy to read.

Comment: I understand.I imported the AAR and while steppign into the aar (compiled class) it asked for the sources of the AAR and I selected the root directory of the AAR Android Project.It seems to go inside that and I can do step in and step out.

Comment: real issue now I am facing is AAR contains the native code (i load the Shared lib in one of the AAR classes) but it is failed to load that library and crashes.Is there any setting to debug the native code used inside the AAR sources.?

Comment: Sorry, I have neither written nor used native code.

Comment: Do I need to every time download and import AAR manually as a module or can I somehow configure it to change the version and be added as a module automatically?