# Implementation of Compiled code is hidden Kotlin Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I've been trying to write a library in kotlin and once the library build is generated as aar file when opening it in Android Studio it is not showing me how my class exactly looks and how the methods are implemented in that.

```
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available

package com.mypackage.dexter

public final class Test private constructor() {

     public final fun testMethod(): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

I've tried Java decompiler plugin in android studio, Kotlin Byte code (This also doesn't show it in the same format that we get if the same code is written in Java). The ultimate thing that I wanted to achieve by looking at the code is that I want to use debugger in the library and evaluate things while running my application where this library is integrated.

Comment: Probably related: [How to debug android library module in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42532062/295004)

Comment: No, in the above link it is doing debugging on the actual code, my use case is to see how actually kotlin generated the class file for the code I've written and then I want to add debugger on the generated code, not the actual code.

Comment: We can’t see what you did wrong unless you show how you created your library and how you’re loading it in the other project. If you’re using Gradle/maven, you need to generate a separate sources jar.